# My searchbox with ajax is not working in django

Tags: python, ajax, django, search

i am developing a project with django, is a eCommerce shop. And i want to implement a searchbox to search the products on it.

I have developed with ajax, but at the moment that i search a product. It shows me all the products that i have and not just only tha product that i want.

This is my view for the searchbar:

```
def searchBar(request, option):

    busqueda = request.POST.get('busqueda', '')
    categoria = Clasificacion.objects.filter(existencia=True)
    items = Articulo.objects.filter(nombre_producto__icontains = busqueda)
    contexto = {
        'items':items,
        'categoria':categoria,
    }
    return render(request, 'adminview/article.html', contexto)
```

this is the html with the form calling the view:

```
<form action="{% url 'adminview:searchBar' option=1 %}" method="get" class="d-none d-sm-inline-block form-inline mr-auto ml-md-0 my-2 my-md-20 navbar-search">
            <div class="input-group">
              <input type="text" id="busqueda" class="form-control bg-light border-1 small" placeholder="Buscar producto..." aria-label="Search" aria-describedby="basic-addon2" name="busqueda">
              <div class="input-group-append">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">
                  <img src="{% static 'img/search.png'%}"width="20px" height="20px" />
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </form>
   ...
   <script src="{% static 'js/search.js'%}"></script>
```

My urls:

```
url(r'^search/ajax(?P<option>\d+)/$', searchBar, name="searchBar"),
url(r'^buscar/searchAjax/$', searchBar),
```

And this is my script from javaScript to do that if you need it:

```
    $(function(){
    $(‘#busqueda’).keyup(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: “POST”,
            url: “searchAjax/”,
            data: {
                ‘busqueda’: $(‘#busqueda’).val(),
                ‘csrfmiddlewaretoken’: $(“input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]”).val()
            },
            success: searchSuccess,
            dataType: ‘html’
        });
    });
});

function searchSuccess(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
{
    $(‘#resultado_busqueda’).html(data);
}
```

Hope you can help me, thank you!.

Comment: If you're getting data back, and it's correct data but just not filtered down to the correct subset, then it seems likely that the problem is in your `searchBar` view. You should probably write some unit tests for it to verify what happens after each character typed is added.  Maybe think about what happens if the user types faster than your ajax call..?

Comment: I think the data is correct, because if search "lavadora" i get the url "search/ajax1/?busqueda=Lavadora". But if i write one unit is the same.

Comment: Surely you first get `127.0.0.1:8000/adminview/search/ajax1/?busqueda=L`, then `127.0.0.1:8000/adminview/search/ajax1/?busqueda=La`, then `127.0.0.1:8000/adminview/search/ajax1/?busqueda=Lav`, etc., no?

Comment: When the user press the submit button it gets the entire word, if i write "Lavadora" and i press the button, i get 127.0.0.1:8000/adminview/search/ajax1/?busqueda=Lavadora

Comment: I think the error is because the word that im searching is not received by the view. Because if i modify the view like this `busqueda = request.POST.get('busqueda', 'lavadora')` i get the product that i wrote. Anyway, i dont know what this happen. If you can help me i apreciatte :)

Comment: Well, that's because your form has `method="get"` which means that `request.POST` will be empty. However, if this question is about regular form submission then you should remove all the ajax stuff since it's not germane to the question.

Comment: What can i do to send the thing that i wrote in the form, to the view?. I am new at django :(

Comment: You are sending the data with POST in the ajax, but GET in the form. Change the form to have `method="POST"` and you should be good to go. If that doesn't work you'll need to do some work on refining your question (ie. remove everything that isn't relevant to the specific problem you're seeing).

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing GET and POST requests

```
type: "POST",
```

should be

```
type: "GET"
```

and

```
busqueda = request.POST.get('busqueda', '')
```

should be

```
busqueda = request.GET.get('busqueda', '')
```

Comment: Yes you are right, i was confusing with GET and POSTS requests. i correct those and it works. Thank you!.